# Account messed up on command line

Tags: git, github, cloud9

I'm in a slight dilemma in which my GitHub account isn't working properly. Whenever I commit to a repository it shows that I pushed changes as 'prohacker112', an account I've never signed into. I'm using `credential-cache`, in which I signed in with my account and whenever it prompts me for a username/password I use my account. So why does GitHub think I'm committing/pushing as prohackr112? How can I tell Git my actual username? I'm using cloud9, if that helps.

Comment: You probably need to change your email in your local git config, [as per these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/).

Comment: No, I've tried the `git config --global user.email "<my email>@gmail.com"` about 3 times now... and no, I did not leave it as `<my email>`, I simply blanked it out here.

Comment: Try running `git config user.email` (without the --global flag) in the repo affected to see if the output matches what you set globally.

Comment: @NathanArthur all right, then should I just delete the question and reset my cloud9?

Comment: I'm not familiar with using cloud9. Someone else can probably help you more with that.

Comment: I'd suggest leaving your question for a day or two at least to see if someone can give you a better answer. Generally there's a better solution than deleting your question.

Comment: @NathanArthur Actually, your solution worked - I had cloned the repo before changing the global config and didn't realize it wasn't linked. If you want to put that in an answer I'll accept it, otherwise just let me know and I'll answer it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email address in your Git config is not set correctly.

To see the global Git email setting, run this command:

```
git config --global user.email
```

If this is incorrect, update it using this command:

```
git config --global user.email "<my email>@gmail.com"
```

If that setting is already correct, or correcting it doesn't fix your problem, check the local setting from within your local repo:

```
git config user.email
```

And, if incorrect, update it with this command:

```
git config user.email "<my email>@gmail.com"
```

[GitHub's relevant documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using [`credential-cache`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache):

this has nothing to commit authorship, which is solely determined by `git config user.name`

> So why does GitHub think I'm committing/pushing as prohackr112?

It depends on the url used to reference the GitHub repo: see the output of `git remote -v`.

If it is an ssh one `git@github.com:user/repo`, then it is possible the public key used by your Cloud 9 account (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, [as seen here](http://blog.thefirehoseproject.com/posts/setting-up-a-cloud9-development-environment/)) is the one registered as `prohackr112`.

You would need to change it by private/public key of your other account.
Or you would need to change the url by an https one, in order to user an account/password set of credentials (which can be cached by your credential helper)